# LogException: LOG003: Read failure At GlassFish

Tags: glassfish

Can anyone help with this error? 
I'm using GlassFish Open Source Edition 3.1

[#|2016-04-17T01:58:16.116+0900|SEVERE|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.CosTransactions|_ThreadID=20;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|JTS5022: Unexpected exception [{0}] from log.
com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.LogException: LOG003: Read failure. Log exception at point 14.
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.LogControl.openFile(LogControl.java:579)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.Log.open(Log.java:223)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.CoordinatorLog.openLog(CoordinatorLog.java:1163)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.CoordinatorLog.formatLogRecords(CoordinatorLog.java:1042)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.CoordinatorLog.write(CoordinatorLog.java:536)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.TransactionState.setState(TransactionState.java:752)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.TopCoordinator.prepare(TopCoordinator.java:2000)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.CoordinatorTerm.commit(CoordinatorTerm.java:357)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.TerminatorImpl.commit(TerminatorImpl.java:250)
        at com.sun.jts.CosTransactions.CurrentImpl.commit(CurrentImpl.java:623)
        at com.sun.jts.jta.TransactionManagerImpl.commit(TransactionManagerImpl.java:323)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.jts.JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.commitDistributedTransaction(JavaEETransactionManagerJTSDelegate.java:186)
        at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:858)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:5114)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4879)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2039)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1990)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:213)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:79)

Comment: While there is no information on the Internet about this error creating a new glassfish domain solved the problem. We had the problem on GF4.

Comment: same problem here... creating a new domain fix this? Isn't there a more specific approach?

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but the following did fix it for us:

1. Stop the glassfish server
2. Do backup the following directory: domain_directory\logs\server\tx
3. Do cleanup the following directory: domain_directory\logs\server\tx
4. Restart the glassfish server

I hope this helps someone.